# RHEL + OS with XFS file system while adding additional partition with diff definition

Tags: redhat, hard-drive, filesystems, partition, xfs

We have the following disk - sda ( in server production - very important server )

sda is the disk of the OS ( rhel 7.2 )  , and file system is `xfs`

`sda` is physical disk

Xfs created with - `mkfs.xfs -f -n ftype=0 /dev/sda`

```
lsblk
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0 558.4G  0 disk
├─sda1             8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2             8:2    0 557.9G  0 part
  ├─rhel0-lv_root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─rhel0-lv_swap 253:1    0    16G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─rhel0-lv_var  253:2    0   100G  0 lvm  /var
sdb                8:16   0   5.5T  0 disk /var/DB
[root@server_prod01 ~]# pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  rhel0 lvm2 a--  557.88g 391.88g
```

Since we have from `Pfree 391G`

We want to add additional partition – `sda3` and builds `xfs filesystem` on `sda3` but little different as `mkfs.xfs -f -n ftype=1`

Is it possible ?

Comment: You will make a new logical volume, not a new partition.

Comment: can you please share you post with example , do you means to add a new disk?

Comment: You have 391 GB free in your LVM VG. So just add another LV.

Comment: can you please show me , by your post ? ( not understand how we can do mkfs on new LV )

Comment: do you mean procedure like in the link - https://www.tecmint.com/add-new-disks-using-lvm-to-linux/